# Unable to see Link Preview In Bot Framework WebChat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am unable to see the preview of any link in the webchat. Can you please suggest to me if this feature is available or not and if available, can you please let me know how to implement this as we have to implement this on a high priority as this has been raised as a production issue from the clients.

Comment: Hi Rajdeep, what did you try so far?

Comment: Hi @Hessel, As I am new to this field, I don't have much idea on how to implement this. This is a client requirement raised as a production issue and they want to see the link preview as well in the response in webchat. Hence, I need to understand if webchat supports this feature and if it supports it, how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: I don't think webchat has anything like that out of the box. There are ways to render your own stuff in the responses by the bot. Lots of it is available in the samples in guthub.

Comment: Linking your GitHub question, and its associated answer, here for visibility: [Unable to see Link Preview In Bot Framework WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4124#issuecomment-1024515316)